# How to increment some randomly chosen elements which are greater than zero?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I have the following matrix:

```
M =[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  6  0 ;
     0  0  0  0  3  0  3  3 ;
     0  0  0  9  9  6  9  6 ;
     0  0  0  9  6  9  9  0 ;
     0  0  0  0  6  3  0  0 ;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ;
     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ];
```

and I want to add `1` in ten randomly chosen elements of `M` which are greater than `0`.

How to do this?

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking. Please elaborate more the 'random' and 'amount of time' things.

Comment: I want to add a random element with 1. Lets say, that i have 10 Apples and i want to assign 1 Apple to a random person one at a time. How can i do this in Matlab.? I hope that my question is clear.

Comment: And you can only give a total of 1 apple to each person? Or you can give them multiple apples, 1 each time?

Comment: 1 Apple to each person.

Comment: Lets say, that i make a loop that executes 10 times and each round i give 1 apple to a random person.

Comment: You should edit this information into the question itself so that it's clearer. Hopefully that will avoid or reduce the number of downvotes/close votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the indices of the elements greater than zero and generate `n` random samples from those indices which will be incremented. Then simply add `1` to the elements at those `n` random indexes.

```
n=10;           %No. of elements of M greater than zero which will be incremented by 1
t1 = find(M>0); %Finding indices of elements of M which are greater than zero
t2 = randperm(length(t1)); %Generating random indices from which first n will be selected
M(t1(t2(1:n))) = M(t1(t2(1:n)))+1  %Incrementing elements of random n indices
```

If you have *Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox*, you can use the following simpler
solution using [**`randsample`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
n=10; 
temp = randsample(find(M>0),n);
M(temp) = M(temp)+1
```

Comment: This answer is much simpler than @beaker. But what one man finds simpler might not be the same case for someone else... +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can select which elements to increment by creating a random permutation of the positions of the non-zero elements.

```
m = 10;   % we want to increment 10 elements
elements = find(M);   % positions of the nonzero elements
rand_order = randperm(numel(elements), m);   % generate random permutation
M(elements(rand_order)) = M(elements(rand_order)) + 1;
```

`randperm` ensures that each nonzero element will only be selected once, in a random order.

Comment: You are best! Thank you :)

Comment: `find(M>0)` will be better (in case if any element of `M` is less than zero). (Although in this case number of apples cannot be negative)

Comment: @SardarUsama Yes, if there are negative values and you don't want them incremented, you should filter them out.

Comment: Using a loop is bad for a simple answer.

Comment: @TonyTannous Yes, I assumed that the OP wanted to increment one element and then perform some operation on the updated matrix before incrementing the next. I'll clarify.

Comment: @TonyTannous That's a bit harsh! Loops aren't really that bad

Comment: @beaker yes I see now what you meant.

Comment: @SardarUsama harsh ? I didn't downvote him.. just mentioned a loop is bad, what if he wants to modify half of his matrix. That would be a huge complexity. And he gets +1 now :)

Comment: @TonyTannous We're all good... constructive criticism is constructive. ;)